# PHP hit counter does not record everything or delete file if have hundreds of hits in a minute

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a hit counter that works without a database. It's simple code and works, but sometimes it doesn't seem to count all visits and other times it deletes the file that stores the visits, this when it receives hundreds/thousands of visits per minute.

```
var pageURL = window.location.href;
var player = videojs('content_video');

    player.one('play', function() {
       var linkcount = pageURL.substr(pageURL.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
          $.ajax({  
                         url:"../send_count.php",  
                         method:"POST",  
                         data:{data:linkcount},  
                         dataType:"text"
                 }); 
    });
```

and this is the sendcount.php that register on file.

```
$data = $_POST['data'];

$data2 = explode("&", $data);

include 'links/'.$data.'.php';

$url = "videos/".$user."/".$link.".dat";

$count = file_get_contents($url);
$count++;
file_put_contents($url,$count);
```

What's wrong?

Comment: This technique just doesn't scale. You'll need to find a better way to handle such a high losd.

Comment: Do you recomend to change some piece on this code?